# Always show error on hot reload. Please suggest how to resolve it?

Tags: flutter, dart

**This error always shows me when I Hot reload or whing I update something in my pubs.**

'''
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/binding.dart:88:3: Error: Type 'ui.Window' not found.
ui.Window get window => ui.window;
^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:60:14: Error: Type 'ui.Window' not found.
required ui.Window window,
^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:88:9: Error: Type 'ui.Window' not found.
final ui.Window _window;
^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:60:17: Error: 'Window' isn't a type.
required ui.Window window,
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:88:12: Error: 'Window' isn't a type.
final ui.Window _window;
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:129:29: Error: Type 'ui.Window' not found.
MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.Window window)
^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:129:32: Error: 'Window' isn't a type.
MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.Window window)
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1900:15: Error: Getter not found: 'runtimeType'.
"$runtimeType's children must not contain any null values, "
^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:353:15: Error: Getter not found: 'opaque'.
assert(opaque),
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:380:15: Error: Getter not found: 'opaque'.
assert(opaque),
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page.dart:48:15: Error: Getter not found: 'opaque'.
assert(opaque),
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page.dart:189:15: Error: Getter not found: 'opaque'.
assert(opaque),
^^^^^^
Performing hot restart...                                              -/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:129:29: Error: Type 'ui.Window' not found.
MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.Window window)
^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/binding.dart:88:3: Error: Type 'ui.Window' not found.
ui.Window get window => ui.window;
^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:60:14: Error: Type 'ui.Window' not found.
required ui.Window window,
^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:88:9: Error: Type 'ui.Window' not found.
final ui.Window _window;
^^^^^^^^^
|/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page.dart:48:15: Error: Getter not found: 'opaque'.
assert(opaque),
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page.dart:189:15: Error: Getter not found: 'opaque'.
assert(opaque),
^^^^^^
-/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1900:15: Error: Getter not found: 'runtimeType'.            "$runtimeType's children must not contain any null values, "
^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:129:32: Error: 'Window' isn't a type.
MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.Window window)
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:353:15: Error: Getter not found: 'opaque'.
assert(opaque),
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:380:15: Error: Getter not found: 'opaque'.
assert(opaque),
^^^^^^
-/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:60:17: Error: 'Window' isn't a type.
required ui.Window window,
^^^^^^
/D:/Devlopment/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:88:12: Error: 'Window' isn't a type.
final ui.Window _window;
'''

Comment: If you update something on pub you should always restart the app as there are some dependency changes.

Comment: I did  but always showing me that

Comment: can u try `flutter clean` and then re-running the app?